# Want to replace NaN by taking average of other sensors

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning, imputation

I have a `df` with `DateTimeIndex` (hourly readings) from multiple sensors

```
Time                   Temp1   Temp2   Temp3  Humidity1 Humidity2 
1/2/2017 13:00          31       23      NA     66        48
1/2/2017 14:00           22      NA      NA      63        43
1/2/2017 15:00           25      25      21      41        39
```

I would like to replace missing values of Temperature sensor 3 (Temp3) with available data from Temp1 and Temp2. If both Temp1 and Temp2 are not null, I want to take an average. If only 1 is available, I will take that value.

Expected Output:

```
Time                      Temp3   
1/2/2017 13:00               27     
1/2/2017 14:00               22      
1/2/2017 15:00               21
```

I tried to use apply with lambda, but running into issues when one of the data is missing.

```
Df['Temp3'] = Df.apply(
    lambda row: (row['Temp1']+row['Temp2'])/2 if np.isnan(row['Temp3']) 
    else row['Temp3'],
    axis=1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this with:

```
df.loc[df['Temp3'].isnull(), 'Temp3'] = df.loc[df['Temp3'].isnull(), ['Temp1', 'Temp2']].mean(axis=1)
```

For example:

```
>>> df
   Temp1  Temp2  Temp3
0     31   23.0    NaN
1     22    NaN    NaN
2     25   25.0   21.0
>>> df.loc[df['Temp3'].isnull(), 'Temp3'] = df.loc[df['Temp3'].isnull(), ['Temp1', 'Temp2']].mean(axis=1)
>>> df
   Temp1  Temp2  Temp3
0     31   23.0   27.0
1     22    NaN   22.0
2     25   25.0   21.0
```